# Derivative under a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How does one find ${\partial y\over \partial t}$ and ${\partial^2 y\over \partial t^2}$ of a double integral $$y(x,t)=\int\limits_0^t \int\limits_{x-t+\xi}^{x+t-\xi} F(\eta)\,\,\,d\eta \,\,\,d\xi$$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Leibnitz Integral Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).